# add_action for save_post_{type} resulting in WSOD

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm helping a non-profit to keep a site working (made by different people over the years) and we recently upgraded WP from the latest 4.x version to 5.2.4 . A few days ago I found an issue with a custom post type that is registered in a home grown plugin.

The error is triggered when I **navigate** to the *add new* page for the custom post type `talk` or when I edit and click **update** in an existing `talk`. There are no messages logged on the WP debug log or email to the WP admin email address.

The code that registers the custom type is (simplified slightly)

```
function wdm_talk_post_type() {
        $labels = array(
                'name'                   => _x( 'Talks', 'post type general name', 'wdm_teacher' ),
                'singular_name'          => _x( 'Talk', 'post type singular name', 'wdm_teacher' ),
                'menu_name'              => _x( 'Talks', 'admin menu', 'wdm_teacher' ),
                'name_admin_bar'         => _x( 'Talk', 'add new on admin bar', 'wdm_teacher' ),
                'add_new'                => _x( 'Add New', 'teacher', 'wdm_teacher' ),
                'add_new_item'           => __( 'Add New Talk', 'wdm_teacher' ),
                'new_item'               => __( 'New Talk', 'wdm_teacher' ),
                'edit_item'              => __( 'Edit Talk', 'wdm_teacher' ),
                'view_item'              => __( 'View Talk', 'wdm_teacher' ),
                'all_items'              => __( 'All Talks', 'wdm_teacher' ),
                'search_items'           => __( 'Search Talks', 'wdm_teacher' ),
                'parent_item_colon'      => __( 'Parent Talks:', 'wdm_teacher' ),
                'not_found'              => __( 'No teachers found.', 'wdm_teacher' ),
                'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No teachers found in Trash.', 'wdm_teacher' )
        );

        $args = array(
                'labels'                 => $labels,
                'description'            => __( 'Description.', 'wdm_teacher' ),
                'public'                 => true,
                'publicly_queryable'     => true,
                'show_ui'                => true,
                'show_in_menu'           => true,
                'query_var'              => true,
                'rewrite'                => array( 'slug' => 'talk' ),
                'capability_type'        => 'post',
                'has_archive'            => true,
                'hierarchical'           => false,
                'menu_position'          => null,
                'supports'               => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
        );

        register_post_type( 'talk', $args );

}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'wdm_talk_meta_box' );

function wdm_talk_post_save($post_id,$post){
    // I removed the body of the function, to test this bug.
    // The original code stores some custom fields
}
add_action('save_post_talk','wdm_talk_post_save');
```

If I comment the line that adds the action `save_post_talk`, the site works fine, but the logic to store the custom fields is not triggered.

Can someone spot the issue? I'm not a wordpress guru (but do have plenty of experience programming in other languages).

Comment: there is 2 arguments for this post then try `add_action('save_post_talk','wdm_talk_post_save', 10, 2);`

Comment: @Kaperto gosh, I just realised that the 4th argument is the number of arguments passed to the callback. If you want, please add your answer so I can accept it. Thanks!!!!